# C, pointers, console vanishes upon entering data

Tags: c, pointers

Hello and thanks in advance,

In short, what I do is create a pointer which creates a local variable on the Stack and then I request memory by malloc which allocates space in the heap.

Then I create a local int on the stack.

Then I request users input through scanf.

But upon entering the last digit, the console vanishes and does not print me the result even if I try to hold it through getchar()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 80

int main()
{
    char *student = malloc(MAX_LINE * sizeof(char));
    int grade;

    printf("Enter students name ");
    scanf("%s", student);

    printf("Enter students grade ");
    scanf("%d", grade);// i would say it has to be grade and not &grade
    // it vanishes right after here. Cant get to see any result
     printf("%s received a %d\n", student, grade);

    free(student);
    getchar();



}
```

Comment: Even if you write &grade, it crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("%d", grade);` should be `scanf("%d", &grade);`

You should pass the *address* of the variable/buffer where you want to store the input element. And `grade` refers to the content, there the `&` addressof operator operating on `grade`  `&grade` gives us the address of the variable.

In case of `scanf("%s", student);`  the `student` itself refers to the address , ie the contents of the pointer variable `student` which contains the base address of the memory block you just allocated. Therefore this is correct.

The arguments should always point to the *address* of the location of the variable/buffer where you want `scanf` to put that particular section of that input.

Say initially you have the garbage `0x5964` stored in `grade`, and the memory address of `grade` is `0x1234abcd`. In `scanf ("%d", grade);` , `scanf` would try to write the read in integer into the memory location `0x5964`, which is invalid.

Whereas in `scanf ("%d", &grade);` , `scanf` would store the read in integer into the memory location `0x1234abcd`. After this referring to `grade` as r-value would get you the contents on the memory location `0x1234abcd` , this is what you want.

```
   +----------+                                   
   | 0x5964   |  <-------(uses this as address)---+-------------------+
   +----------+  <------+                         |                   |
   |  grade   |     (writes)       scanf ("%d", grade);               |  
   +----------+      (here)        scanf ("%d", &grade);              |
   |0x1234abcd|         |                         |                   |
   +----------+  <------+(uses this as address)---+                   |
                                                                      |
                                                                      |
   +----------+                                                       |
   |  ??????  | <----------(tries to write here)----------------------+
   +----------+
   |   ???    |
   +----------+
   |  0x5964  | 
   +----------+
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I am going to embed this in my head even if I have to read it 10 times. I am reading quite a lot of tutorials but each was incomplete so from all of them i was trying to make the whole picture. These explanations here in this thread are outstandingly good. Thank you!

Comment: What confused me was the use of scanf, because with local variables, i did not have problems. I often did something like, int *ptr; and then int x = 5; and then ptr = &x; whereby i could tell that *ptr = 5; but scanf was acting differently.

Comment: you do not need to care about if it is from stack or from heap, what you want to make sure that the address you are are passing to `scanf` is a valid allocated address. in `int *ptr;` and `int x;` and `ptr = &x`  now because we have stored the address of `x` as the value of `ptr` so we pass `&x` or we pass `ptr` is the same, as they both represent the same address value, which is of a local variable, and therefore valid.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment is incorrect, it needs to be `&grade` because you need to pass the *address* of `grade` so that `scanf` can modify it through the memory address. If you pass just `grade`, you're passing `scanf` the *value* of `grade`, which is some random garbage (or possible 0 depending on your compiler) because you didn't initialize it. `scanf` then thinks that the random number (or 0...) is an address and tries to modify the memory at that address, and that causes a crash.

To make `getchar` pause the program, call `fflush(stdin)` after the second call to `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand and agree, but, even if I correct it. It crashes the same. I dont know why

Comment: @retarded call `fflush(stdin)` after you call `scanf` the second time. `scanf` reads the input but doesn't 'remove' it from the buffer so when you call `getchar` it sees a character and returns. Please mark this as the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Thank you! brilliant! it works! now it stops and lets me see the printing

Answer (score 2):

You should use `scanf("%d", &grade);`. `scanf()` needs to know *where* to write data, so it needs address of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash or just not print the result?
How does it crash?

Anyway (after adding the address-of operator to `grade`), you should always check the return value of `scanf`. In this case it should return 1 if all is well, 0 (or EOF) otherwise.

```
int chk = scanf("%d", &grade);
if (chk == 1) {
    /* rest of your program */
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "something went wrong in the scanf.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Return value was %d\n", chk);
}
```

I suspect you input a name with embedded spaces (like `"full name"`). Doing that will assign `"full"` to `student` and leave `" name"` in the buffer ready for next input operation. Trying to get an integer from there will fail and scanf returns 0 to indicate that failure.